# app.UseSwagger() fails when hosting .net core web api in InProcess on IIS

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, swagger

I wonder if anyone has come across this problem before?

I am using .net core 3.1 for my WebApi, and swagger 5.0. 
When trying to host the WebApi InProcess under IIS.

When I have this line of code 
`app.UseSwagger()`
commented out the page renders. If I uncomment it then the server throws a 500 error. 
Clearly, something is up with swagger being in use but I'm scratching my head on this one now.

Anyone got any advice, I am certainly willing to listen because I am stumped.

Comment: Please add minimum reproducible code. Please provide how did you configure swagger. Startup.cs contains many important info.